# Spring Roo RooDataOnDemand and RooIntegrationTest

Tags: spring-roo

How to Use `RooDataOnDemand` and `RooIntegrationTest` annotated classes from Spring Roo?

Answer (score 1):

@RooIntegrationTest annotated classes will contain tests to verify the crud functionality of the model object.

If you change any other standard behaviour of the model objects, then you will need to also change this class, and also the @RooDataOnDemand class.  A common case is where you change the model to not use auto-generated id.  This will require a change to the data on demand object to set an id.

You can see these tests in action by running:

```
mvn test
```